# How can I add custom dimensions to a custom report in google analytics

Tags: facebook, google-analytics, universal-analytics

I just set up some custom dimensions in google analytics e.g. one dimension is for facebook login status another for twitter and so on. Now i want make an custom report for the social login status of my visitors.

My tracking works. I checked it with the google analytics debugger.

How can I add custom dimensions to custom reports in google analytics?

Answer (score 2):

Just select the custom dimension you'd like to see from the list of dimensions.

[image]